# TraitsUI - Joining views

Tags: python, model-view-controller, traits, traitsui

Reading the documentation about applying the MVC pattern with TraitsUI, I read the example [MVC_demo.py](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/examples/demo/Advanced/MVC_demo.py). Now, I'm wondering how to manage multiple "MVC".
I want to write some "includeallMVCs.py" and to have something like:

```
import MyViewController1, MyViewController2, MyViewController2

class IncludeallMVCs(HasTraits):
    view = Include(MyViewController1, MyViewController2, MyViewController3)
```

Where MyViewController, MyViewController, MyViewController are classes like the MVC_demo sample.

So, the idea is to separate differents views with their controllers, and then "join" all of them in only one "generic" view.

Comment: Can you articulate a slightly more fully formed question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching in the examples I found this one: [Dynamic Forms Using Instances](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/examples/demo/Dynamic_Forms/dynamic_form_using_instances.py)
Then I modified it to separate an AdultHandler. In this example I use the salary variable to be controlled by AdultHandler.

File: **adult.py**

```
from traitsui.api import Handler
class AdultHandler(Handler):
    def object_salary_changed (self, info):
        if (info.object.salary >= 20000):
            print "Good Salary!"

        else:
            print "Bad Salary"
```

File: **adult_model.py**

```
from adult import AdultHandler

class AdultSpec ( HasTraits ):
    """ Trait list for adults (assigned to 'misc' for a Person when age >= 18).
    """

    marital_status   = Enum( 'single', 'married', 'divorced', 'widowed' )
    registered_voter = Bool
    military_service = Bool
    salary = Int

    traits_view = View(
        'marital_status',
        'registered_voter',
        'military_service',
        'salary',
        handler = AdultHandler()
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = AdultSpec()
    a.configure_traits()
```

File: **main.py**

```
from adult_model import AdultSpec

class Person ( HasTraits ):
    """ Demo class for demonstrating dynamic interface restructuring.
    """
    datainput       = Instance( AdultSpec )

    # Interface for attributes that depend on the value of 'age':
    spec_group = Group(
        Group(
            Item( name = 'datainput', style = 'custom' ),
            show_labels = False
        ),
        label       = 'Additional Info',
        show_border = True
    )

    # A simple View is enough as long as the right handler is specified:
    view = View(
        Group(
            spec_group
            ),
        title     = 'Using MVC',
        buttons   = [ 'OK' ],
        resizable = True,
        width = 300
    )

# Create the demo:
demo = Person( datainput = AdultSpec() )

# Run the demo (if invoked from the command line):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo.configure_traits()
```